# BLToolKit save null instead of 0

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, c#, orm

(Can't use it as tag, but we're Using BLToolkit as ORM)

I have this weird problem where BLToolkit saves NULL instead of 0 in our database.

If you look the image, this is my values that will be saved. (gIdx stand for GroupIndex)
[image: Values when the Stored Procedure is being executed]

Here are the results in the database. If you look at the GroupIndex Column, i only have 1 and 2. (this thing happen also for the SortIndex column)
[image]

this is my stored proc. And the column is simply a NULL, INT

```
USE [ASTUSADMINISTRATION]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[stpr_GridColumnLayout_Update]    Script Date: 2015-06-22 08:08:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stpr_GridColumnLayout_Update]
    @ID AS [usrID],  
    @Width AS int,
    @Index AS int,
    @IsCellMerged AS [usrBoolean],
    @GroupIndex AS int,
    @SortIndex AS int,
    @SortDirectionType AS int,
    @SummaryItemType AS int,
    @UpdatedDate AS datetime OUTPUT,
    @UpdatedUser AS [usrUsername]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET @UpdatedDate = GETDATE()

    -- Vérifier si c'est un groupe système
UPDATE [dbo].[GridColumnLayout] SET
    [Width] = @Width,
    [Index] = @Index,
    [IsCellMerged] = @IsCellMerged,
    [GroupIndex] = @GroupIndex, 
    [SortIndex] = @SortIndex,
    [SortDirectionType] = @SortDirectionType,
    [SummaryItemType] = @SummaryItemType,
    [UpdatedDate] = @UpdatedDate, 
    [UpdatedUser] = @UpdatedUser
  WHERE [GridColumnLayoutID] = @ID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about putting a default constraint value of 0 for the fields in question?

Comment: This is not an answer, but thanks. I have found the problem within the BLToolkit module, and created an issue on GitHub. It has been fixed on July 27th.

Comment: My apologies for giving you a non-answer.  Glad you were able to figure it out.